# ionic capacitor run iOS failed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cocoapods, cross-platform, capacitor

I'm using MacBook Air m1 for ionic+angular development. When I try to run the "ionic capacitor run ios", it shows below error message. Works well with ionic capacitor run android. Also tried with open using rosetta in terminal. Any help would be really appreciate.
[image]

[image: vscode terminal]

Answer (score -1):

The native project is not in sync with your dependencies..
`npx cap run ios` will not sync your project, it will just copy the code changes...

run this command once `npx cap sync ios` and then `npx cap run ios`

[Reference](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cli/run)

Comment: Still the same error. it says "[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Capacitor":"

Comment: why don't you run it from the native ide xcode first.? use `npx cap open ios` build it from xcode first.. if this doesn't work, remove your ios folder and add it again..